# zinc (red dot) Holistic Method

Tags: punctuation

In the picture attached, a woman holds a placard which reads:
Covid Cures
Hydroxychloroquine
ZPAK  $14.00
zinc
(red dot)
Holistic Method

---

The red dot seems to link zinc with holistic method, I am not sure. What does it function or mean?
[image]

Source: Nature
[How COVID broke the evidence pipeline](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01246-x)

Note: If the picture doesn't show here, click the [link](https://media.nature.com/lw800/magazine-assets/d41586-021-01246-x/d41586-021-01246-x_19139514.jpg) to watch.

Comment: It is just a visual separation/or, I think.

Comment: Note: the banner is suggesting that people use a fake method to deal with Covid. It is all the more annoying that the seller has hi-jacked the US flag to adorn their dangerous lies.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yep, it's crap. Crap, crap, crap. Can't say it enough. :) All these lies are so **disheartening**. The other day some stupid guy was standing near our town line in New England with a piece of cardboard that read: Don't get the jab. He looked completely drunk and had also done the pro-orange man at election time. What planet are these people from?

Comment: We have them here in the UK too, including [the brother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Corbyn) of Jeremy Corbyn, the former leader of the Labour Party.

Comment: It's scary to think that the likes of what happened in the 1930s, e.g. the Nazis and their lies and dismissal of 'Jewish science' , etc, are back with a vengeance. And just as dangerous.

Comment: Corbyn's brother thinks George Soros is to blame for Covid! Steve Bannon's had a massive effect on world politics: politicians have learnt that The Masses don't care who's in power as long as he makes them feel good. Or good 'n angry. Like in 1930s Germany, people don't want difficult truths: they want easy conspiracy theories and solutions they can understand. "China did it." "Build a wall." "It's Soros." "It's the Jews."

Answer (score 2):

It's a visual separator here, used to emphasize the end of the list of alleged "COVID cures" from the descriptor "holistic method". Additionally, if you look closely, you can see dots between each name along the sides and bottom of the poster so that you can easily tell where one name ends and another begins.

This dot is also commonly seen on the web, for example when searching in Google I see:

> [How to change the title separator in Yoast SEO • Yoast](https://yoast.com/help/title-separator/)

The dot separates the article title from the site name here. (Additionally, the article itself explains how to set up a separator like this when using their software.)